# A tool to compare structural MRIs recorded at different times

Tags: neuroimaging

I have two MRI's from the same person with a Huntington disease, recorded at different time points (with different MRI machines).

I would like to compare the MRIs to see how the disease progresses. Could you say, is there a standard tool (or at least a standard approach) allowing to compare them? I mean, just having two brain slices from different MRIs side by side to eyeball them.

Comment: By MRIs, do you mean that you have two photos? If they're just photos, this may be more of a medical question that could only be answered by a radiologist (depending on the photos). If you have structural MRI data, you could compare the datasets quantitatively.

Comment: @jrcalabrese no, I mean two MRI sequences (DICOM). And yes, I mean quantitative comparison. I just need a tool to do it. It is not obvious because one has to align them, normalize values and so on. Surely someone has made a software for it

Comment: Have you read [Andy's Brain Book](https://andysbrainbook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)? You may consider converting [DICOM to NIFTI](https://andysbrainbook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/MRIcroGL/MRIcroGL_2_dcm2nii.html) and then you should be able to use SPM or AFNI with the NIFTI files.

Comment: @jrcalabrese I thought this is a stackexchange website. I looking for a practical answer, not for a reference to a huge book. I know how to convert DICOM to NIFTI, the question is what to do after that. Not just "go use a huge poorly documented excruciatingly complicated scientific package" (SPM), but a set of steps I could potentially perform

Comment: When it comes to neuroimaging, Andy's Brain Book is one of the most straightforward guides available and SPM is one of the most commonly-used packages for MRI statistical analysis. There is no one-size-fits-all sets of steps to perform on MRI data.

Comment: @demitau This is a StackExchange website, yes, but it sounds like you're looking for a "write my code for me" answer which has never been acceptable on SO or across the network. There are lots of decisions to make along the way, not just a button to press and voila.

Comment: It would be better to study a resource like jrcalabrese references, and use this reading to ask a more specific question about something you're stuck on in the reference. Otherwise, how is anyone to know that you, for example, already know about format conversions? Nothing in your question identifies what you know and don't know.